# Half of my disk space is assigned to Ubuntu. How can I move some to Windows?

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

I don't need half my disk space on Ubuntu and I would love to move it back to Windows without having to uninstall and install Ubuntu all over again. I'd appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Ubuntu live-CD and run Gparted to change the allocated partitions on your disk.  You can also download GParted and create a dedicated bootable CD or USB drive.  A tutorial on the use of Gparted is available at:  http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html

Note that, depending on your disk setup, you may have to shrink the Ubuntu partition first in order to create some unallocated space, and then move the Ubuntu partition to the right so that the unallocated space is immediately to the right of the windows partition.  You can then resize the Windows partition to use all the unallocated space.  This assumes that Windows was loaded first and occupies the front of the drive.